# Не работает required в полях

Tags: html, css, form, html-form

У меня не срабатывает required у полей input, подскажите в чём я ошибся

```
<form action="#" class="cart-form">
                  <h3 class="cart-form-title mb-3 pb-3">Заказ</h3>
                  <h4 class="cart-form-subtitle mb-4">Отправитель</h4>
                  <div class="row mb-5">
                    <div class="col-12">
                      <label class="form-group">
                        <span class="form-label">Отправитель</span>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="Отправитель"
                          required
                        />
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <label class="form-group mb-0">
                        <span class="form-label">Телефон отправителя</span>
                        <input
                          type="tel"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="Телефон отправителя"
                          required
                        />
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <label class="form-group mb-0">
                        <span class="form-label">Email отправителя</span>
                        <input
                          type="email"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="Email отправителя"
                        />
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="cart-form-delivery mb-5">
                    <li>
                      <label class="form-checkbox">
                        <input
                          class="form-check-input"
                          type="radio"
                          name="flexRadioDefault1"
                          id="flexRadioDefault3"
                        />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault3">
                          Доставка курьером
                        </label>
                      </label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <label class="form-checkbox">
                        <input
                          class="form-check-input"
                          type="radio"
                          name="flexRadioDefault1"
                          id="flexRadioDefault4"
                          checked
                        />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault4">
                          Самовывоз
                        </label>
                      </label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <h4 class="cart-form-subtitle mb-4">Адрес</h4>
                  <label class="form-group">
                    <span class="form-label">
                      Вы сможете забрать товар в нашем салоне
                    </span>
                    <select class="form-control">
                      <option value>Выберите адрес</option>
                      <option value="address1">
                        Домодедово Путейская 30/6
                      </option>
                      <option value="address2">
                        Домодедово Комсомольская 1А
                      </option>
                      <option value="address2">
                        Домодедово, Дорожная, с. 10
                      </option>
                    </select>
                  </label>
                  <h4 class="cart-form-subtitle mb-4">Получатель</h4>
                  <label class="form-group">
                    <span class="form-label">Получатель</span>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="Получатель"
                      required
                    />
                  </label>
                  <label class="form-group">
                    <span class="form-label">Телефон получателя</span>
                    <input
                      type="tel"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="Телефон получателя"
                      required
                    />
                  </label>
                  <label class="form-group mb-0">
                    <span class="form-label">Адрес доставки</span>
                    <input
                      type="email"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="Адрес доставки"
                    />
                  </label>
                  <label class="form-checkbox my-5">
                    <div class="form-checkbox-text">
                      Связаться с получателем
                    </div>
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      class="form-checkbox-input"
                      checked=""
                    />
                    <i class="form-checkbox-icon"></i>
                  </label>
                  <h4 class="cart-form-subtitle mb-4">Дата доставки</h4>
                  <div class="row mb-5">
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <label class="form-group">
                        <span class="form-label">Дата</span>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="Дата"
                        />
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <label class="form-group">
                        <span class="form-label">Время</span>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="Время"
                        />
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                      <label class="form-group mb-0">
                        <span class="form-label mb-1 pb-2">
                          Текст открытки
                        </span>
                        <textarea
                          type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="Текст открытки"
                        ></textarea>
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <h4 class="cart-form-subtitle mb-4">Способ оплаты</h4>
                  <ul class="cart-form-payment">
                    <li>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <input
                          class="form-check-input"
                          type="radio"
                          name="flexRadioDefault"
                          id="flexRadioDefault1"
                        />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
                          Наличными
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <div class="form-check">
                        <input
                          class="form-check-input"
                          type="radio"
                          name="flexRadioDefault"
                          id="flexRadioDefault2"
                          checked=""
                        />
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
                          Банковской картой online
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100 mt-5">
                    Оформить заказ
                  </button>
                </form>
```

Comment: Проверил ваш код, `required` отрабатывает прекрасно

Comment: При отправке почему то не высвечивается уведомление о том. что необходимо заполнить поле

Comment: @Smekalinho добавьте к `input` атрибут `name`. Разные браузеры могут по разному реагировать на `required` без `name`

Comment: пустой атрибут к ```input``` ? Почему то именно в хроме не отображается это сообщение

Comment: не пустой, а уникальный, строковый. _Почему то именно в хроме не отображается это сообщение_, если перенести ваш код в сниппет прямо тут на SO, то все работает как должно